# can someone confirm my isolation level understanding please

Tags: sql-server-2008

There are Five Isolation levels summary is mentioned below… Please correct me if I am wrong : -

1. Read uncommited. In this level we can read dirty pages and chages can be done(DML statements like Insert and Update) on the rows even when records are not commited.
2. Read Committed. Only committed rows can be read. If transaction is open at the time records are read deadlock will happen. Modifications to the data(Inserts and Updates) can be done even if transaction is not complete or not
3. Repeatable Read. Will be Read commited + any update can happen only after the END TRANSACTION but insert command(Phantom insert) will do the changes even if data is not committed.
4. Serializable. Rows can not be inserted using INSERT command and niether can UPDATE command work in uncommitted transaction nor can uncommitted data be read
5. Snapshot.  If there are two transactions T1 and T2. Commmitted data will be seen only after both these transactions are committed. If these two transactions are conflicting with each other then transaction will fail completely and transaction will be rollback

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic

Comment: What I mean is to check the ISOLATION LEVEL OPTIONS for - SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL STATEMENT IN SQL SERVER 2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first understand underline problems that isolation level resolves.

1. **Dirty read**(I saw updated record however it disappeared again)
2. **Non repeatable read**(Update - I saw an updated value but now value has
   changed. Oh someone rolled back.)
3. **Phantom read**(Insert - This appeared as a ghost and then disappeared)

Try to play around on two connections. First run connection 1 script then connection 2 script without committing anything. Once both scripts are executed then try to commit connection 1.

*READ UNCOMMITTED* - Connection running under this isolation level can read rows that have been `modified by other transactions` but not yet committed.

*READ COMMITTED* - Connection running under this isolation level cannot read data that has been modified but not committed by other transactions.

*REPEATABLE READ* -  Transaction running under this isolation level cannot read data that has been modified but not yet committed by other transactions **and** that no other transactions can modify data that has been read by this transaction until the this transaction completes. This is done by placing shared lock on records read by this transaction. Having a shared on lock record, no other transaction can modify this record until this transaction completes.

*SERIALIZABLE* - Same conditions as we have for repeatable read with an addition of one more condition i.e. Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current transaction until the current transaction completes.
Think of a record as inserting a record between date range. You are trying to insert a record between the date range read by another connection.

### DIRTY READ

**Connection 1**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE tbl SET Col1 = 'Dummy' WHERE ID = 1

--NO COMMIT YET
```

**Connection 2**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ID = 1 -- will return you 'Dummy' if script 
                                  on connection 1 executed first. Since transaction on 
                                  connection 1 hasn't been committed yet, you did a dirty 
                                  read on connection 2.

--NO COMMIT YET
```

### Avoiding Non repeatable read

**Connection 1**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 5 --Issue shared lock.  This prevents 
                               other transactions from modifying any 
                               rows that have been read by the current transaction. 

--Not committed yet
```

**Connection 2**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 5
UPDATE tbl set name='XYZ' WHERE ID = 5 -- this will wait until transaction
                                       at connection 1 is completed. 
                                      (Shared lock has been taken)
--Not committed yet
```

### Avoiding Phantom read

**Connection 1**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Age BETWEEN 5 AND 15 -- This will issue range lock

--Not committed yet
```

**Connection 2**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO tbl (Age) VALUES(4) -- Will insert successfully
INSERT INTO tbl (Age) VALUES(7) -- this will wait until transaction
                                       at connection 1 is completed. 
                                      (Range lock has been taken)
--Not committed yet
```

Comment: Your explanation is very clear and precise..

Comment: @sam, thanks I could help.